# Flask Travis CI failing build

Tags: flask, travis-ci

I am a noob in Travis CI. I created a simple hello world flask app and integrated that with Travis CI. My .travis.yml is like this

```
os:
  - linux
language: python
python:
  - "2.6"
  - "2.7"
# command to install dependencies
script: python app.py
branches:
  only:
    - master
```

Where app.py is the application.The app.py ran successfully while building since it doesnt return anything travis considered it as build fail. What could be the possible fix? I am attaching a screenshot of the build error message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are running the dev server unconditionally.  Place it in a guard:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Change the command to run your tests, rather than the app.  Travis is used to build and test, not run your server.